# Any ways to earn by getting clicks and views?

Tags: freelance-websites, legal, project

I can get a minimum of 5000 views/clicks per day. Is there any that I could use this skill?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like sites that are nothing but click traps so just having "5000 clicks per day" alone seems a bit shallow to me.
If your content is good and you get a lot of visitors that way you should maybe start to monetize your content. One way to do this is to participate in an affiliate program. Or - if your content is really unique - you could ask people to pay for it.

The middle ground would be to join Patreon or some similar sponsorship site to ask people for a bit of financial support.